# linq to entities nested query hang

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, linq-to-entities

When making a nested query then it works fine in a console application and unit test but it doesn't work when called via a webservice, it simply hangs.

When I debug it then it hangs when I loop the inner loop, even though my sample data returns an empty array.

My solution is to make seperate queries pr. top query, but I would like to hear if anyone can say what I do wrong with the nested query.

```
var query = await (from row in context.<MyTable>
            where <something>
            select new
            {
                row.<whatever>,
                Lines = from line in row.<NestedTable> select new
                {
                    line.<whatever>
                }
            }).ToListAsync();

foreach(var item in query)
{
    foreach(var line in item.Lines)
    {
        <here it hangs>
    }
}
```

Can someone pinpoint what it wrong?

Comment: Part 1 : Lines is coming from a file where the end of file closes the input steam so the linq know where the end of the data is found.  When coming from a webservice you have a stream with no end of file.  A stream stays open until the process that opens the stream closes it.  A file stream the windows operating system closes the stream.  With a service you can have a race condition if the process that opens the stream closes it before the second process reads the data.

Comment: Part 2 :  One way of solving the issue is to add a byte count to the beginning of the stream so the 2nd process know where the end of data is located; or add a terminating character to the stream (that is not a character in the stream) so the end can be determined.

Comment: @jdweng I think you could be correct but it is slightly beyond my technical level. How would that code with a bytecount look? And would that be more complex than tossing the linequery into the loop instead?

Comment: Usually you would add either 4 (int) or 8 (long) bytes to beginning of stream using byte[] len = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length);  Then  extract count from input stream using : MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
            stream.Read(buffer,0,4);